# Separate Code javascript without using jquery ($ symbol) knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good. I want to separate my code without using Jquery lib(symbol $).
I am trying this method: 
This is my App.js

```
var window.myGlobalVariable = {}; 
(function(namespace){
    (function App(){    
        var app1 = myGlobalVariable.app1 ; 
    });
    namespace.App = App;
})(window.myGlobalVariable);
```

this is my app1.js

```
(function(namespace){
    (function app1 (namespace){
        //do something   example : console.log("hello world")
    });
namespace.app1 = app1 ; 
})(window.myGlobalVariable);
```

but it does not work....
(error: app1  is undefined)

> I must create a Webpage  with lib knockout.js but i cannot  use 
>   jquery

some suggestions?

Comment: Try different name than App - afaik it is reserved :P

Comment: Please be more specific: exactly what is not working? How is knockout.js coming into this picture?

Comment: @Lashus: who reserved `App`? Its not! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Comment: I don't get it what you try to do. Why do you put the clojure scoped function in parentheses? What exactly is the question? What has your code to do with either jquery or knockout?

Comment: You don't put a function declaration in parentheses. Instead, you have to write `namespace.app1 = function () { ... };` You also don't have to pass `namespace` to the `app1` function, just use it, it's global to the clojure scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a slight mistake with the initialization of the "namespace" variable.

This will work:

```
// Note that I've removed 'var'
window.myGlobalVariable = {}; 
(function(namspace){
    function App(){    
        var app1 = myGlobalVariable.app1 ; 
    };
    namespace.App = App;
})(window.myGlobalVariable);
```

In reality you will probably have several of these scoped things in you application. In that case, I think this is better:

```
(function(namspace){
    namespace.App = function(){    
        // Do what you need to do.
    };
})(window.myGlobalVariable = window.myGlobalVariable || {});
```

The expression `window.myGlobalVariable = window.myGlobalVariable || {}` uses the instace if present otherwise initializes it. This way, the order of your modules make no difference at all.

Comment: oh i'm so stupid... now it  work ...I do not understand how I missed it

Comment: You also need to lose some of the innermost parenthesis.